# Как получать кадры из компонента <video></video>?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, видео, webgl

Скажите, пожалуйста, как мне получать кадры с видео, используя тег `<video></video>`, чтобы их можно было обработать и вывести на канвас?

Answer (score 3):

При помощи `WebGL/GLSL` можно загружать кадры видео как текстуру и манипулировать полученными изображениями.

В примере ниже к текстуре применяется эффект во фрагментном шейдере,копируем картинку 3 раза, одну картинку мы не трогаем, вторую копию мы перевернем и сделаем негатив, а у третьей копии изменим цвет

```js
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 3*(canvas.height = 185);
document.body.append(canvas);
document.body.style.margin = 0;

let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
let texture = initTexture(gl);
let video = setupVideo('https://i.imgur.com/Pfa2ZxZ.mp4');
let pid = gl.createProgram();

shader(`
  attribute vec2 coords;
    void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

shader(`
  precision highp float;
  uniform sampler2D texture;

  vec4 sample(vec2 uv) {
      return texture2D(texture, uv);
  }

  vec4 frag (vec2 uv) {
  
    if (uv.x > 0.333 && uv.x < 0.666) {
        uv.x *= 3.;
        uv.x -= 1.;
 
        return vec4(1.0 - sample(1.0-uv).xyz, 1.0);
    }
    
    if (uv.x >= 0.666) {
        uv.x *= 3.;
        uv.x -= 2.;
        float d = dot(uv-0.5,uv-0.5);
 
        return vec4(1.0 - smoothstep(0.2,0.,d)*sample(1.0-uv).yzx - smoothstep(0.,0.2,d)*sample(uv).zyx, 1.0);
    }
    
    uv.x *= 3.;
    return sample(uv);
  }

  void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = frag(vec2(
        gl_FragCoord.x / ${canvas.width}.,
        1. - gl_FragCoord.y / ${canvas.height}.
      ));
  }
`, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let array = new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, array, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let al = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(al, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al);

var textureLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, "texture");
gl.uniform1i(textureLocation, 0);

function shader(src, type) {
    let sid = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
    gl.compileShader(sid);
    var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
    gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
    if (message.length > 0) {
        console.log(src.split('\n').map(function (str, i) {
            return ("" + (1 + i)).padStart(4, "0") + ": " + str
        }).join('\n'));
        throw message;
    }
}

function drawTriangle() {
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

function render(now) {
    updateTexture(gl, texture, video);
    drawTriangle();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);

function setupVideo(url) {
    const video = document.createElement('video');
    var playing = false;
    var timeupdate = false;
    video.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    video.autoplay = true;
    video.muted = true;
    video.loop = true;
    video.addEventListener('playing', function() {
        playing = true;
        checkReady();
    }, true);
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        timeupdate = true;
        checkReady();
    }, true);
    video.src = url;
    video.play();

    function checkReady() {
        if (playing && timeupdate) 
            copyVideo = true;  
    }
    return video;
}

function initTexture(gl) {
    const texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA,1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        new Uint8Array([0, 0, 0, 255]));
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    return texture;
}

function updateTexture(gl, texture, video) {
    const level = 0;
    const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
    const srcFormat = gl.RGBA;
    const srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,
        srcFormat, srcType, video);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const
video = document.getElementById ('video1'),
canvas = document.getElementById ('canvas1')


video.onclick = () => {

  canvas.width = video.videoWidth
  canvas.height = video.videoHeight
  
  canvas.getContext ('2d').drawImage (video, 0, 0)
}
```

```html
<video id="video1" width="100" autoplay loop>
<source src="https://i.imgur.com/Pfa2ZxZ.mp4"></source>
</video>
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
```