# Обязательно ли нужно рендерить <video> в DOM чтобы срисовывать с него кадры в canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Всем добрый день. Может кто значет canvas хорошо и сможет подсказать. Могу ли я отрисовывать video в canvas с помощью метода drawImage и при этом не добавлять не canvas не video tag в DOM? Или хотя-бы только canvas.

Comment: тег video добавлять в Dom не обязательно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960366/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-video-video/960400#960400

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Вижу спасибо, но там в DOM добавляют canvas. А если и canvas не добавлять будет работать?

Comment: то что попадает на экран - должно быть в dom

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в моем случае мне нужна просто делать скриншот и получать этот скриншот в виде src.

Comment: тогда и канва не нужна

Comment: @StrangerintheQ понял спс)