# Браузерная склейка нескольких видео в одно с transitions используя WebAssembly + FFmpeg

Tags: canvas, видео, ffmpeg, webassembly

Необходимо в приложении на React объединить несколько видео **на клиенте** загружаемых с сервера в одно, добавив **переходы** между ними и показать пользователю, возможно используя canvas.

Анимации переходов нужны как в [FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade). С помощью CSS все их не сделать. Других библиотек с подобным набором переходов я не нашёл, хотя искал долго решение на canvas.

Для решения задачи больше всего (судя по длительным поискам) подходит WebAssembly + FFmpeg.
Но практическая реализация этого мне не поддаётся.

Пожалуйста, не скидывайте гайды, я их все уже перечитал. Библиотеки FFmpeg.js и прочие тоже перепробовал.
Если есть кто-то с реальным опытом, буду благодарен, если поделитесь.

Comment: Если сразу показывать пользователю, то зачем ffmpeg? Почему бы не просто повесить css-анимацию на обычные теги video?

Comment: @andreymal добавил описание.

Comment: пожалейте клиентов, не заставляйте их крутить ffmpeg в браузере

Comment: @user7860670 знал бы я другой рабочий путь, сделал бы иначе. Впрочем, ffmpeg я тоже пока не могу использовать. Хотя с WASM по идее это должно работать очень быстро.

Comment: webgl, шейдеры.. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960366/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-video-video/960400#960400